# What to include in Python Docstrings?

Tags: python, class, object

I would like to know what python docstrings include? Like if I want to document a certain class, what things should I write in the docstring for that class?

Answer (score 4):

According to [PEP 257 -- Docstring Convention](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/):

> The docstring for a class should summarize its behavior and list the
>   public methods and instance variables. If the class is intended to be
>   subclassed, and has an additional interface for subclasses, this
>   interface should be listed separately (in the docstring). The class
>   constructor should be documented in the docstring for its `__init__`
>   method. Individual methods should be documented by their own
>   docstring.
>
> If a class subclasses another class and its behavior is mostly
>   inherited from that class, its docstring should mention this and
>   summarize the differences. Use the verb "override" to indicate that a
>   subclass method replaces a superclass method and does not call the
>   superclass method; use the verb "extend" to indicate that a subclass
>   method calls the superclass method (in addition to its own behavior).